# How to call get or any method of requests library of python by passing a method name to function argument?

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

I am using requests library of python. I wanted to call requests method GET,POST or any method depend on the arguments received in the function call. I will call requests method inside that function. How can i achieve this?

```
import requests

def get_endpoint(method,shop, list_obj):
    join_sentence = '/'.join(list_obj)
    endpoint_api = "https://{0}/admin/2019-04/{1}.json".format(shop, join_sentence)
    a = requests.method(endpoint_api) # this method should be replaced by method argument of a function get_endpoint
get_endpoint('get', "https://abc/", ['john','joe','1368797932'])
```

I expect it will replace method with get,post whichever passed to function and that url will invoke.
For ex. requests.get(endpoint_api) # get is replaced by method and it will call the url.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a dictionary for example:

```
def get_endpoint(method,shop, list_obj):
    method_f = {
        "get": requests.get,
        "post": requests.post,
        ... 
    }
    def invalid_method(*_):
        raise ValueError("Method not supported")
    join_sentence = '/'.join(list_obj)
    endpoint_api = "https://{0}/admin/2019-04/{1}.json".format(shop, join_sentence)
    a = method_f.get(method, invalid_method)(endpoint_api) # this method should be replaced by method argument of a function get_endpoint
```

Notice that I added a default function to raise an error if you do not support the method. The error is just for the example purposes and you can raise whatever you need.

Answer (score 1):

As of today and referring to the [documentation](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#custom-verbs), you can make use of the `requests.request` function which has an extra HTTP verb argument. From your example:

```py
import requests

def get_endpoint(method, shop, list_obj):
    join_sentence = '/'.join(list_obj)
    endpoint_api = "https://{0}/admin/2019-04/{1}.json".format(shop, join_sentence)
    a = requests.request(method, endpoint_api)

get_endpoint('GET', "abc", ['john','joe','1368797932'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use python `eval` method to invoke methods with string. Though I am not sure If it's the recommended way to do that.

```
import requests

def get_endpoint(method,shop, list_obj):
    join_sentence = '/'.join(list_obj)
    endpoint_api = "https://{0}/admin/2019-04/{1}.json".format(shop, join_sentence)
    return eval('requests.' + method)(endpoint_api)

get_endpoint('get', "https://abc/", ['john','joe','1368797932'])
```